# How to find max values in dictionary and return key when multiple key have the same max value

Tags: python

As the title suggests I'm trying to find a way to return the key with the max value in a dictionary. This is what I have tried so far but I've been getting the TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable.

```
winners = {1931: ['Norman Taurog'], 1932: ['Frank Borzage'], 1933: ['Frank Lloyd'], 1934: ['Frank Capra'], 1935: ['John Ford'], 1936: ['Frank Capra'], 1937: ['Leo McCarey'], 1938: ['Frank Capra'], 1939: ['Victor Fleming'], 1940: ['John Ford'], 1941: ['John Ford'], 1942: ['William Wyler'], 1943: ['Michael Curtiz'], 1944: ['Leo McCarey'], 1945: ['Billy Wilder'], 1946: ['William Wyler'], 1947: ['Elia Kazan'], 1948: ['John Huston'], 1949: ['Joseph L. Mankiewicz'], 1950: ['Joseph L. Mankiewicz'], 1951: ['George Stevens'], 1952: ['John Ford'], 1953: ['Fred Zinnemann'], 1954: ['Elia Kazan'], 1955: ['Delbert Mann'], 1956: ['George Stevens'], 1957: ['David Lean'], 1958: ['Vincente Minnelli'], 1959: ['William Wyler'], 1960: ['Billy Wilder'], 1961: ['Jerome Robbins', 'Robert Wise'], 1962: ['David Lean'], 1963: ['Tony Richardson'], 1964: ['George Cukor'], 1965: ['Robert Wise'], 1966: ['Fred Zinnemann'], 1967: ['Mike Nichols'], 1968: ['Carol Reed'], 1969: ['John Schlesinger'], 1970: ['Franklin J. Schaffner'], 1971: ['William Friedkin'], 1972: ['Bob Fosse'], 1973: ['George Roy Hill'], 1974: ['Francis Ford Coppola'], 1975: ['Milos Forman'], 1976: ['John G. Avildsen'], 1977: ['Woody Allen'], 1978: ['Michael Cimino'], 1979: ['Robert Benton'], 1980: ['Robert Redford'], 1981: ['Warren Beatty'], 1982: ['Richard Attenborough'], 1983: ['James L. Brooks'], 1984: ['Milos Forman'], 1985: ['Sydney Pollack'], 1986: ['Oliver Stone'], 1987: ['Bernardo Bertolucci'], 1988: ['Barry Levinson'], 1989: ['Oliver Stone'], 1990: ['Kevin Costner'], 1991: ['Jonathan Demme'], 1992: ['Clint Eastwood'], 1993: ['Steven Spielberg'], 1994: ['Robert Zemeckis'], 1995: ['Mel Gibson'], 1996: ['Anthony Minghella'], 1997: ['James Cameron'], 1998: ['Steven Spielberg'], 1999: ['Sam Mendes'], 2000: ['Steven Soderbergh'], 2001: ['Ron Howard'], 2002: ['Roman Polanski'], 2003: ['Peter Jackson'], 2004: ['Clint Eastwood'], 2005: ['Ang Lee'], 2006: ['Martin Scorsese'], 2007: ['Ethan Coen', 'Joel Coen'], 2008: ['Danny Boyle'], 2009: ['Kathryn Bigelow'], 2010: ['Tom Hooper']}

win_count_dict = {}
most_win_director = []

for yr,dir in winners.items():
    for director in dir:
        if director not in win_count_dict:
            win_count_dict[director]=1
        else:
            win_count_dict[director]+=1

max_frq=win_count_dict[max(win_count_dict,key=win_count_dict.get)]  

for dirk,freq in win_count_dict.items():
    if freq==max_frq:
        most_win_director.append[dirk]
    else:
        continue

print("most_win_director = {}".format(most_win_director))
```

Comment: `dir` is a bultin, change that to `dir_` or `directors`, also change `most_win_director.append(dirk)`

Comment: The immediate problem is that `most_win_director.append[dirk]` has the wrong parentheses; square brackets perform indexing, and you cannot index the `append` method.  Going forward, please include the full traceback so we don't have to copy your code just to see where the error happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename `dir` to something else like `_dir` as it a builtiin function and you also have the wrong syntax for appending an item to a list, `most_win_director.append[dirk]` it should be `most_win_director.append(dirk)`.

```
win_count_dict = {}
most_win_director = []

for yr,_dir in winners.items():
    for director in _dir:
        if director not in win_count_dict:
            win_count_dict[director]=1
        else:
            win_count_dict[director]+=1

max_frq=win_count_dict[max(win_count_dict,key=win_count_dict.get)]  

for dirk,freq in win_count_dict.items():
    if freq==max_frq:
        most_win_director.append(dirk)
    else:
        continue

print("most_win_director = {}".format(most_win_director))
```

**Output**:

```
most_win_director = ['John Ford']
```